Setting up and Querying Temporal Tables in .NET 7
Using .NET 7 Entity Framework, I have a system of tables that mark as Temporal, so that I can reconstruct the data structure from the past (i.e. when a user makes a change, I should be able to roll back the change to a previous state). For the most part, it seems to work fine, but when I try to query a table that has Many-To-Many relationships, that's where the issues arise.
Here is my code:
 var timeConstraints = dbContext
     .MyParrentDB
     .TemporalAll()
     .Where(c => c.Id == id)                  
     .Select(
         c => new
         {             
             PeriodStart = EF.Property<DateTime>(c, "PeriodStart"),
             PeriodEnd = EF.Property<DateTime>(c, "PeriodEnd"),
         })
     .Single();

 var foundItem = await dbContext.MyParrentDB
     .TemporalFromTo(timeConstraints.PeriodStart, timeConstraints.PeriodEnd)
     .Where(c => c.Id == id)
     .Include(x => x.ExampleManyToManyTable!.Where(p => p != null))
          .ThenInclude(c => c.ChildTable)
     .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
 

But this throws an error:

Navigation expansion is only supported for 'AsOf' temporal operation. For other operations use join manually.

So, what is the correct way to query the temporal table?  Here is how I setup the tables and their relationships:
public class MyParrentDB 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;     
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;       
    public ICollection<ExampleManyToManyTable>? ExampleManyToManyTable { get; set; } 
}
public class ExampleManyToManyTable
{
    public int MyParrentDBId { get; set; }
    public MyParrentDB MyParrentDB { get; set; }
    public int ChildTableId { get; set; }
    public ChildTable ChildTable { get; set; }
}
public class ChildTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public ICollection<ExampleManyToManyTable>? ExampleManyToManyTable { get; set; }
}

Setting up the table relationships: 

    public DbSet<MyParrentDB> MyParrentDB { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExampleManyToManyTable> ExampleManyToManyTable { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ChildTable> ChildTable { get; set; }   
    
       modelBuilder.Entity<ExampleManyToManyTable>()
          .HasKey(bc => new { bc.MyParrentDBId, bc.ChildTableId });
       modelBuilder.Entity<ExampleManyToManyTable>()
          .HasOne(bc => bc.MyParrentDB)
          .WithMany(b => b.ExampleManyToManyTable)
          .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.MyParrentDBId);
       modelBuilder.Entity<ExampleManyToManyTable>()
          .HasOne(bc => bc.ChildTable)
          .WithMany(c => c.ExampleManyToManyTable)
          .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.ChildTableId);   
           
       modelBuilder.Entity<MyParrentDB>().Property<DateTime>("PeriodStart");
       modelBuilder.Entity<MyParrentDB>().Property<DateTime>("PeriodEnd");
       
       modelBuilder.Entity<MyParrentDB>().ToTable("MyParrentDB", c => c.IsTemporal());
       modelBuilder.Entity<ChildTable>().ToTable("ChildTable", c => c.IsTemporal());
       modelBuilder.Entity<ExampleManyToManyTable>().ToTable("ExampleManyToManyTable", c => c.IsTemporal());

EDIT:
I changed the SQL to use TemporalAsOf. To view the query string I added:
var sql = _context.MyParrentDB
    .TemporalAsOf(test.PeriodStart)
    .Where(c => c.Id == id)
    .Include(x => x.ExampleManyToManyTable!
       .Where(model => model != null))
       .ThenInclude(tags => tags.ChildTable)
    .ToQueryString();

Which outputs:

  DECLARE @__id_0 int = 9;

  SELECT 
   [a].[Id], 
   [a].[Description], 
   [a].[Name], 
   [a].[PeriodEnd],
   [a].[PeriodStart], 
   [t].[MyParrentDBId], 
   [t].[ChildTableId],
   [t].[PeriodEnd], 
   [t].[PeriodStart], 
   [t].[Id], 
   [t].[PeriodEnd0],  
   [t].[PeriodStart0], 
   [t].[ChildName] 
FROM [MyParrentDB] 
FOR
SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '2024-07-10T14:30:36.1001535' 
 AS [a] LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT 
        [a0].[MyParrentDBId], 
        [a0].[ChildTableId], 
        [a0].[PeriodEnd],
        [a0].[PeriodStart], 
        [a1].[Id], 
        [a1].[PeriodEnd] AS [PeriodEnd0],
        [a1].[PeriodStart] AS [PeriodStart0], 
        [a1].[ChildName] 
       FROM
        [ExampleManyToManyTable] FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF
  '2024-07-10T14:30:36.1001535' 
       AS [a0] INNER JOIN [ChildTable] 
       FOR
         SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '2024-07-10T14:30:36.1001535' AS [a1] ON
        [a0].[ChildTableId] = [a1].[Id]) AS [t] ON [a].[Id] =
       [t].[MyParrentDBId]    
        WHERE [a].[Id] = @__id_0  
        ORDER BY [a].[Id],
       [t].[MyParrentDBId], [t].[ChildTableId]


Table Data:


So, why do not use TemporalAsOf(timeConstraints.PeriodStart)?

I tried that.  It does complete the search without an error, but it pulls back the incorrect Many to Many records.  I am not sure if that is because it needs the start and end dates or if its because my setup is not correct?

Which query is generated with TemporalAsOf. Update question with SQL.

I have updated my question with the SQL statement that is created.  Thanks!

SQL Looks good. Try to analyse what is stored in Temporal tables on this date, usually they have suffix History.

Thanks @SvyatoslavDanyliv.  I updated my question to show the data I have.  So, if I query by PeriodStart of '2024-07-10T14:30:36.1001535'  I would expect to not get any child records and just have the Parent record, but I am actually getting a child record

According to the data, there is one child active at T14:30:36,1001535, the 9-1 row. That one ends at .1124118, After which point I am guessing it was deleted?

As for the original question about how to do it FromTo, you would need to join context.A.FromTo with context.B.FromTo, though it's not that simple as you would be fetching a history of As where within the same range of time one or more historical renditions of the related Bs will be applicable. If I ask for what changes were made to table A over a range I may get back 1 or more rows, but there make be many changes to the related Bs in that time-frame so EF would need to work out and create A snapshots based not just on A histories, but Bs, Cs, etc. AsOf produces 1 snapshot.

@jason, try AsNoTracking(), maybe there are already children in ChangeTracker.

Thanks!  I was able to get it to work!

NP, so many times, when commenting, I forgot that EF Core can add to result entities which are already tracked.

That was the issue.  When EF Core updated the record, if I did two saves (i.e. updated the main record and then added a child record in a different save call) it would create two history records.  Once I updated how I was saving changes, it worked!
